# Reuse bundle (application) id in different project for new version of app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm updating a version of my app, but in a new Xcode project. The app uses CloudKit, meaning the bundle id must be the same. At the moment an error message saying the bundle id must be unique is displayed when running the app. How do I use the same bundle id for testing the new update of the app.

Comment: Are you using the same development team?

Comment: Yes both are in the same development team

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: upon building it says failed to create provisioning profile. The app id *** cannot be register to your development team. change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again

Comment: Probibabky the previous version of your app had a manually created provisioning profile so Xcode cannot automatically create a new one. Log in to developer.apple.com and download the old provisioning profile and add it to Xcode.